# Super simple Node application, problems with ä,ö etc. characters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having problems with my super simple Node application. Whenever I use encodeURIComponent() my ä, ö, @ etc. characters gets broken. Here's a simple example code:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'});
  res.end(encodeURIComponent('äöäöäöäö') + ' äöäöäöäöäö');
}).listen(8081, 'IP_ADDRESS');
```

The part with encodeURIComponent looks like this: %C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%B6

I have double and triple checked that all my files are utf-8 encoded and the same problem happens on my Windows machine aswell as on my Ubuntu 14 server.

Here is a picture of what it looks like on Google Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYspX.jpg

I honestly have no idea what is causing this so I'm hoping I would get some answers from here.

Comment: Your characters are not broken, they're percent-encoded, which is an expected behaviour from `encodeURIComponent`. Try it in your browser console.

Comment: There is nothing broken here. `encodeURIComponent()` is doing exactly what it should be doing, it's encoding the string you passed to it (so that it's suitable for passing in via a url).

Comment: It's not broken, that's what it does. Try it in reverse `decodeURIComponent('%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%B6') === "äöäöäö"`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `encodeURIComponent()` it will encode the string such that your characters `ä` and `ö`can be interpreted in url's. In this case it will convert this into `%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%B6`. This is the expected behaviour and if you run the `decodeURIComponent` on the string and check what the value is, you should recieve you're characters back exactly as before they were encoded.

```
encodeURIComponent('äöäöäöäö') === "%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%B6"

decodeURIComponent('%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%B6') === "äöäöäö"
```

There isn't a problem as this is the intended output of encoding/decoding url's.